# Adding buttons with external links to plotly dash modal

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

New to dash, trying to figure out how to create a modal (pop-up window) that has its own buttons inside it. I have read the dbc docs and they don't seem to discuss how to add content *inside* of a modal that link elsewhere. Ideally, this modal will have a message, but also a button that links to jira. I was thinking something like this:

```
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

modal = html.Div(
   [
       dbc.Button("Open", id="open-centered"),
       dbc.Modal(
           [
               dbc.ModalHeader("Request"),
               dbc.ModalBody("Click the link below to be directed to your request"),
               dbc.ModalFooter(
                   dbc.Button(
                       "Close", id="close-centered", className="ml-auto"
                   )
                   dbc.Button(
                       "External Link", id="link-centered", className="ml-auto"
                   )
               ),
           ],
           id="modal-centered",
           centered=True,
       ),
   ]
)


@app.callback(
   Output("modal-centered", "is_open"),
   [Input("open-centered", "n_clicks"), Input("close-centered", "n_clicks")],
   [State("modal-centered", "is_open")],
)
def toggle_modal(n1, n2, is_open):
   if n1 or n2:
       return not is_open
   return is_open
```

where the External Link button will open a new tab in your browser and navigate to another website, but I'm not sure. Any help and advice is very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is it not working? Are you receiving an error? Not sure what specifically is the problem.

Comment: @coralvanda yes it is not working, I'm not sure where to put the external link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the page you need](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/button/) from the docs. Just add an `href` property to your button. So you would have something like:

```py
dbc.Button(
    "External Link",
    id="link-centered", 
    className="ml-auto",
    href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page'
)
```

Comment: Hi , Is there any way to get the link for from callback ?

Comment: Can you please help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735689/python-dash-plotly-select-a-file-in-a-url-browse-functionality ?

Comment: You want to update the link using a callback? I think you could just use the `href` as the output target of a callback.

Comment: Exactly , but for some reason , it is neither taking the default url nor the new link . A Small code snippet could help me please  Here is my call back @app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('link-centered', 'href'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('out_link', 'value')])
def open_url(link):
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    if not ctx.triggered:
        button_id = 'No clicks yet'
    else:
        button_id = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]
    if (button_id == 'link-centered'):
        return link                  -> Link has a valid url

Comment: Is there any thing i am missing in above code ?

Comment: I don't see `'out-link'` used as an ID anywhere. Is that button missing from your layout?

Comment: out-link is a input parameter which is a Text Box which should store your URL that needs to be opened from the call back.

Comment: Ok, but it isn't in the original post's layout. Is it in your code?

Comment: Sorry . My mistake . its not my question i never shared my layout , I just extended the conversation here based on your answer to my first query related to this question

Comment: I see. I'm not sure what is going wrong there. You could try swapping other components in to check the callback's behavior (ex. output to a div just to make sure it's hooked up correctly, or to a `html.Button` to try the functionality with that).

Comment: I could finally get that working , The call back location was wrong . Corrected it . Thanks